# Black screen when I am trying to install ubuntu (installation settings can't be saved)

Tags: system-installation

The problem is that after I try to install Linux I have black screen and that's all. The only thing that works is grub console.

I've tryed:

> 2 different flash drives

> different USB ports 2.0 and 3.0

> Manjaro and Ubuntu

> different programms for writing iso on flash drives

**Important thing** that I didn't found on internet is that my problem can be fixed by writing **nomodeset**, I tryed this, but after clicking on F10 or Ctrl+x There is **"booting a command list"** in upper left angle, and no action.

I can't find any info about problem like this.

My specs:

- MSI B450 gaming plus
- Radeon rx 580 8gb ARMOR 8G OC
- AMD Ryzen 5 1600